# Python: Parse string objects into python objects from a file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I've got a `.csv` file and I need to get some information from it. If I open the file, I can see two lines in it, that says "data" and "notes", and I need to get the information that these two variables have.

When I open the `.csv` file, it shows these lines:

```
data = 
[0,1,2,3,4,5,3,2,3,4,5,]

notes = [{"text": "Hello", "position":(2,3)}, {"text": "Bye", "position":(4,5)}]
```

To open the file I use:

```
import csv

class A()
  def __init__(self):
    #Some stuff in here

  def get_data(self):
    file = open(self.file_name, "r")
    data = csv.reader(file, delimiter = "\t)
    rows = [row for row in data]
```

Now, to read the information in data, I just write:

```
    for line in row[1][0]:
      try:
        value_list = int(line)
        print value_list

      except ValueError:
        pass
```

And, with this I can create another list with these values and print it. Now, I need to read the data from "notes", as you can see, it is a list with dictionaries as elements. What I need to do, is to read the "position" element inside each dictionary and print it.

This is the code that I have:

```
   for notes in row[3][0]:
     if notes["position"]:
       print notes["position"]
```

But this, gives me this error:
`TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

How can I access these elements of each dictionary and then print it? Hope you can help me.

This is the `.csv` file from where I am trying to get the information.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't appear to actually be a CSV file

Comment: This problem is notes is a string not a dict

Comment: Well, it is. Is just that at the beginning it has one column only. After these lines, is a common `.csv` file.

Comment: @PabloFlores that is not the preferred way to use csv reader >> remove from class.  It is not reccommded to have one function class. Use functions.

Comment: @PabloFlores -- what is row  in  row[1][0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the last part of your code to:

```
for note in eval(rows[3][0].strip("notes = ")):
    if note["position"]:
        print note["position"]
```

If you need the position to be an actual tuple instead of a string, you can change the last line to:

```
print tuple(note["position"])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Isn't "rows" a  list? If it is, then `strip` will give me a `syntax error`. Isn't it?

Comment: @PabloFlores - It is, but rows[3][0] is a string, and that's what you're running strip on. Test the code, it works.

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot.